# Preg_match error in error log

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following error showing up in my error log:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/public/themes/js/imagegallery.php on line 24, referer: http://www.mydomain.com/collections.html
```

Here is the preg match it refers to - does anyone have any idea what it relates to exactly?

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile() && !preg_match('\.jpg$/', $fileinfo->getFilename())) {
        $bgimagearray[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the first delimiter (`/`).

HOWEVER, there is no need for a regex here. You can get the filename by simply doing:

```
$extension = pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 3):

The missing "/" at the beginning of your pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Yup you are not using any delimiters at all in your regex. The engine tries to evaluate the first char in your regex as start-delimiter. Your first char is a backslash. This is not allowed.

Modify your regex this way

```
!preg_match('#\.jpg$#',....
```

Answer (score 0):

A *delimiter* is the character used to denote the start and end of a regular expression. Typically people will use something like `/`, `#`, or `@`, but it can be just about any character.

Try this instead:

```
preg_match('/\.jpg$/', ...
```

That said, it would probably be better to use `substr()` here, no need for regex.

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter is referring to the symbols that surround the RegEx you are using. In this case, you use the proper end-delimiter, but not the beginning one. It should look like this: `preg_match('/\.jpg$/', ...)`